# Tree: How to keep opened states when tree updated

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to keep tree nodes open/closed stated when i set new data to `this.dataSource.data`. New data is very same with old - it just have one or several lowest-level nodes added/removed.

My idea is to record node expansion to `ReplaySubject` and replay expansion queue. It should work but it's very ugly way.

I hope that here are have much more elegant way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

I have a hierarchical structure of data objects to display in a material tree. Each data object gets transformed into a TreeNodeModel containing the ID and the ParentID of the original data object.
In the method that updates the data source the node's expanded state is saved/restored:

```js
// Method that updates the data source
public updateDataSource(dataObjects: SomeDataObject) {
    
  // save node's expanded state
  const expandedNodesIds: string[] = [];
  if (this.treeControl.dataNodes) {
    this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach((node: TreeNodeModel) => {
      if (this.treeControl.isExpandable(node) && this.treeControl.isExpanded(node)) {
        expandedNodesIds.push(node.id);
      }
    });
  }
    
  // update data source
  this.treeDataSource.data = dataObjects;
    
  // restore node's expanded state
  this.treeControl.dataNodes
    .filter(node => this.isActive(node) || expandedNodesIds.find(id => id === node.id))
    .forEach(nodeToExpand => {
      this.expandNode(nodeToExpand);
    });
}
    
// Method that expands the node (if not a leave) and its parent nodes (if any) using the TreeControl
private expandNode(treeNode: TreeNodeModel | undefined): void {
  if (!treeNode) {
    return;
  }
    
  if (this.treeControl.isExpandable(treeNode)) {
    this.treeControl.expand(treeNode);
  }
    
  const parentId = treeNode.parentId ? treeNode.parentId : undefined;
  this.expandNode(this.treeControl.dataNodes.find(node => node.id === parentId));
}

interface TreeNodeModel {
  expandable: boolean;
  level: number;
  id: string;
  parentId: string;
  // most probably some more custom data ;)
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!  One additional thought is that if your code always ensures that the tree is expanded appropriately (i.e. parent before child), then you should be able to replace the expandNode method with a simple call to this.treeControl.expand(nodeToExpand).  This simplifies the code a little bit more.

Comment: hi can you share your TreeNodeModel.. It will be very appreciated

Comment: hi can you please check ths..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452816/how-do-i-save-the-state-of-expanded-tree-in-angular-mat-tree

Comment: @MADMAX I've added the TreeNodeModel interface

Answer (score 3):

I added a boolean 'expanded' to my datamodel. I then use a function on (click) which inverts this, and a recursive loop to save that change to the actual data that is used for dataSource.data. So in reality I am not using the treecontrol anymore, even though I have still need it (the tree does not work without).

```
    <button mat-icon-button
    [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name"
    (click)="changeState(node, myJson)"
    >
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{node.expanded ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
```

--

```
  /** Changes expanded state for clicked tree-item, saves change to json data used by tree datasource */
  changeState(node, myJson) {
    node.expanded = !node.expanded;

    if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
      this.found = false;
      myJson.forEach(child => {
        if (!this.found) {
        this.saveStates(child, node);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  /** recursive loop-function used by this.changeState() to save tree-items expanded-state to the master array */
  saveStates(child, clickedChild) {
    if (child.id === clickedChild.id) {
      child.expanded = clickedChild.expanded;
      this.found = true;
      return;
    } else if (child.children && child.children.length > 0) {
      child.children.forEach(c => {
        this.saveStates(c, clickedGroup);
      });
    }
  }
```

--
And the standard functions from the tree-example I changed like this to work with my data:

```
  // checks if datasource for material tree has any children
  hasNestedChild = (_: number, nodeData: MyModel) => nodeData.children.length > 0;

  // returns children
  private _getChildren = (node: MyModel) => node.children;
```

Comment: Good idea but comparing between old and new `dataNodes` is very expensive operation. Especially if you have ~10k nodes. So, it can't be used in my project.

Answer (score 1):

`this.treeControl.expansionModel.selected` gives you your expanded nodes at the moment so you can save them `this.prevExpansionModel = this.treeControl.expansionModel.selected`  and apply them,like this:

```
 this.prevExpansionModel.forEach(object => this.treeControl.expand(object));
```

Altough it seems to not be abke to close and open again after doing this so you have to figure that out but maybe this will get you closer to your goal